# Provide default value for page title

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I published a single page app (SPA) on the web (using [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org)). The title and meta tags for the pages are getting set dynamically.

The website got indexed by Google and the page title Google read is `{{ Page.title }}`.

I just want to provide a default value for my page title for search engines till the data get set by the controller.

Comment: **Not tested**: Try `<title ng-bind="Page.title">Default title</title>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ng-bind:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
      <title ng-bind="aa">lorem</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>

    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" ng-model="aa" ng-init="aa=15">
    </body>
    </html>
```